# Unable to run moveit because of assimp packages

Tags: moveit, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to run `roslaunch baxter_moveit_config demo_baxter.launch`, I get the error

`/opt/ros/indigo/lib/rviz/rviz: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libgeometric_shapes.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6Assimp8Importer18SetPropertyIntegerEPKciPb`

and it crashes. These are my assimp packages:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep assimp
assimp-utils/trusty,now 3.0~dfsg-2 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.2~dfsg-3~urp8+1]
libassimp-dev/trusty,now 3.2~dfsg-3~urp8+1 amd64 [installed]
libassimp-doc/trusty,now 3.0~dfsg-2 all [installed,upgradable to: 3.2~dfsg-3~urp8+1]
libassimp3/trusty,now 3.2~dfsg-3~urp8+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-pyassimp/trusty,now 3.2~dfsg-3~urp8+1 all [installed]
```

I tried to solve it according to a [previous thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/266321/symbol-lookup-error-libgeometry_shapeso-undefined-symbol-_zn6assimp8importer18setpropertyintegerepkcipb/) but the mentioned solution did not work.

Any help? I feel like I have tried everything that I could but keep going in circles...

EDIT: This is what I did previously:

My assimp libraries were too high, so i reverted them to 3.0 manually (I downloaded the .deb file from launchpad and installed them using dbpk)

```
$ apt list --installed | grep assimp
assimp-utils/trusty,now 3.0~dfsg-2 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.2~dfsg-3~urp8+1]
libassimp-dev/trusty,now 3.0~dfsg-2 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.2~dfsg-3~urp8+1]
libassimp-doc/trusty,now 3.0~dfsg-2 all [installed,upgradable to: 3.2~dfsg-3~urp8+1]
libassimp3/trusty,now 3.0~dfsg-2 i386 [installed,upgradable to: 3.2~dfsg-3~urp8+1]
python-pyassimp/trusty,now 3.0~dfsg-2 all [installed,upgradable to: 3.2~dfsg-3~urp8+1]
```

However, once that was done, I would get this error message when starting rviz:

`/opt/ros/indigo/lib/rviz/rviz: error while loading shared libraries: libassimp.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`

since this didnt work, I did a sudo apt-get -f install again and ended up with the 3.2 assimp versions as mentioned above.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291336/unable-to-run-moveit-because-of-assimp-packages/) by [ysl208](https://answers.ros.org/users/26761/ysl208/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:\

> libassimp.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

and:

> libassimp3/trusty,now 3.0~dfsg-2 i386

you have the 32bit pkg on a 64bit system. That is not going to work.

**Comment by [ysl208](https://answers.ros.org/users/26761/ysl208/) on 2018-05-16**:
this was my previous error message. so should i manually revert the packages again to version 3.0?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
I don't understand what you're trying to say.

**Comment by [ysl208](https://answers.ros.org/users/26761/ysl208/) on 2018-05-16**:
my current version is `libassimp3/trusty,now 3.2~dfsg-3~urp8+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]`, what should i do?

**Comment by [ysl208](https://answers.ros.org/users/26761/ysl208/) on 2018-05-16**:
I edited my post so that it is a bit more clear. Sorry for the confusion

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-17**:
Why did you delete the question? That makes little sense to me.

**Comment by [ysl208](https://answers.ros.org/users/26761/ysl208/) on 2018-05-17**:
I didnt delete the question? it's still there, i marked your answer as correct

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-17**:
The question had the 'deleted' status when I looked at it. I undeleted it. Not sure what happened then. But it's also not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error msg was clear: you cannot use a 32bit library on a 64bit system like that. You could try reverting to the same versions again, but this time install only 64bit packages and see if that works.

No guarantees though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ysl208](https://answers.ros.org/users/26761/ysl208/) on 2018-05-16**:
it worked! thanks!